# how to fix "Function definition is not allowed here" in Xcode

Tags: c

This is my lecture example. And, I follow it.
How to fix the error?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define SPACE ' '

int main(){
    void branching_if_judgement(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            printf("a(%d) is larger than b(%d)\n", a, b);
        }else
        {
            printf("a(%d) is smaller or equal to b(%d)\n", a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that an example that is supposed to work properly or is your task to solve that error?

Comment: Just example only. And, Dr. tell me to add the main function but still fail to run @Gerhardh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function definition/declaration is not allowed in another function.

`main` is a function and `branching_if_judgement` is another function.

correct (read compile-able) code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SPACE ' '

static void branching_if_judgement(const int a, const int b){
    if (a > b)
    {
       printf("a(%d) is larger than b(%d)\n", a, b);
    } else
    {
       printf("a(%d) is smaller or equal to b(%d)\n", a, b);
    }
}

int main(){
   branching_if_judgement(2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Hey, you know how to combine all the function in one output? @puio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64260987/how-to-combine-the-function-in-the-one-output-in-xcode?noredirect=1#comment113635508_64260987