# how to combine the function in the one output in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SPACE ' '
void branching_if_judgement(int a, int b){
    if (a > b){
        printf("a(%d) is larger than b(%d)\n", a, b);
    }else {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        printf("a(%d) is smaller or equal to b(%d)\n", a, b);
    }
}

char branching_if_judgement_char(int a, int b){
    char res;
    if (a > b){
        printf("a(%d) is larger than b(%d)\n", a, b);
        res = 'Y';
    }else {
        printf("a(%d) is smaller or equal to b(%d)\n", a, b);
        res = 'N';
    }
    return res;
}
int main() {
    branching_if_judgement_char(2,3);
}
```

I follow the example to run the code. And, there are missing the main function in the slide. I add it

---

So, my question is how to combine all function in the one output, just like the slide.

[image: how to run the output like the example in the slide?]

:[image: Slide example]

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, but I think they have ignored the `main` function to show you the essence of the code. 
The `branching_if_judgement_char` returns a char, so it seems like you need a variable e.g `result` where you save the value from the function:  `result = branching_if_judgement_char(2,3);`.
Not sure if I got it right. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828670/xcode-doesnt-write-anything-to-output-console

Comment: @user1098490 the link is not helpful since I have selected All Output

Comment: Which line should be saved? @user1098490

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question: *how to combine all function in the one output* @Chun Ki Wu, I am sorry.

Comment: It's fine, my English is not well. My question is how to run the output like the slide example. @user1098490

Comment: if you add in main: `result = branching_if_judgement_char(2,3); printf(result);`. 
Or maybe it's possible to print directly:
`printf(branching_if_judgement_char(2,3));`

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function signature tells us that

```
char branching_if_judgement_char(int a, int b)
```

it returns a thing of type `char`, and it takes two things of type `int`.

So when you call it, you're passing the two things *to* it, but not taking the thing it's returning.

```
branching_if_judgement_char(2,3);
```

Correct code should be

```
char p = branching_if_judgement_char(2,3);
printf("%c\n", p);
```

Please find some time to read

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm